# How can I current-limit a current mode DAC?

Tags: dac, current-limiting, current-sink

I have an OLED display with a current reference input to control brightness.

Absolute maximum brightness is achieved by sinking 12.5uA, which is usually accomplished by a resistor to ground.

I wish to control brightness from my MCU, which has a programmable current-mode DAC.  The DAC is capable of sinking up to 64uA, but I expect the OLED to be damaged at that setting.

I don't want to rely on software alone to protect the device. How can I scale the 64uA maximum sink of the IDAC to the 12.5uA maximum sink of the display?

Comment: Put a resistor in series.

Comment: _Which_ MCU and OLED display, and what are their supply voltages?

Comment: In much the same way as you can build a resistive voltage divider, you can also build a resistive *current divider*.

Comment: @Bruce, the OLED display is UG-2864HSWEG01, and the MCU is EFM32JG1B100F256GM32-C0 . Both are running on 3.3V.

Comment: Your OLED display requires 7.0-7.5V Vcc (either supplied externally or generated by its internal DC/DC converter) and its datasheet implies that the IREF pin has 7V on it (12.5uA with 560k resistor = 7V). Since your MCU is only rated for 3.3V you will need a level shifter to control the current.

Comment: @Bruce, thank you for the insightful comment. I hadn't considered that Vref was that high. I think I will use a digital pot instead of the IDAC since the parts count has to increase anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MCU output is limited to 3.3V maximum, but the OLED display's IREF input sits at ~7V. Therefore as well as reducing the current you will also need to extend the voltage acceptance to >7V. Here's one solution:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fONbf9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The MCU's IDAC is configured to *source* up to 64uA, which is converted to a voltage by R1. OA1, Q1 and R2 create a constant current sink. The op amp maintains the same voltage across resistor R2 as R1, but since R2 is 5 times larger the current through it is 5 times smaller (ie. 12.5uA vs 64uA). Q1 is rated for 45V so 7V is no problem for it.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. This is much more elegant than a digital pot. 

FYI, in my application, since I am using the internal DC-DC, for which they recommend a 390K resistor on IREF,  the implied VREF is 4.875V. What might I need to change in your design?

Comment: I see that I wouldn't have make any change to account for that. I ran a sweep simulation of this on CircuitLab. Very cool. 

Sweeping IDAC from 0...64uA in 0.5uA steps, there is a perfect ramp on IREF from ~0 to 12.5uA ..  but for IDAC=500nA there is a strange spike of ~32uA on IREF.    

Is that a real outcome, or some quirk of the simulation?

Comment: It worked perfectly in LTSpice, so I think it is a simulation quirk. Try reducing the step size to 50nA.